# Calculating item frequencies from single column

Tags: r

I have a set of data where a transaction id always has at least 1 item from both A and B. I want to calculate frequencies where the items from category A are tabulated with respect to those of category B.

Input looks like:

```
id = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
cat = c("A","B","A","A","A","B","B","A","A","B")
item = c("Item 1","Item 30","Item 2","Item 3",
         "Item 1","Item 30","Item 31","Item 1","Item 2","Item 32")
df = data.frame(id,cat,item)

Id  Cat Item
1   A   Item 1
1   B   Item 30
2   A   Item 2
2   A   Item 3
2   A   Item 1
2   B   Item 30
3   B   Item 31
3   A   Item 1
3   A   Item 2
3   B   Item 32
```

The output I'm looking for is

```
        Item30  Item31  Item 32
Item1   2       1       1
Item2   1       1       1
Item3   1
```

I have a solution where I can loop through the unique values of each category, but is there a cleaner solution which avoids the loop entirely?

Edit - Fixed the example which was missing a row. And to clarify, the category {A,B} relates to which category the item belongs to

Comment: Can you show your loop?

Comment: What would the 2 stand for (Item1, Item30)? Also, have you looked into `?table`

Comment: Are you sure the values are correct

Comment: How are your rows and columns related in the output?

Comment: To clarify as in my edit, the category {A,B} differentiates the items themselves. So I want all category A items with respect to category B items as in the output example. In this case, only {Item 1, Item 30} occurred twice  in id # 1 and 2. This is very similar to frequent item set analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be doing

```
with(merge(df[cat=='A',],df[cat=='B',],by='id',all=TRUE),
  table(droplevels(item.x),droplevels(item.y)))
```

```
         Item 30 Item 31 Item 32
  Item 1       2       1       1
  Item 2       1       1       1
  Item 3       1       0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to group by id and cat.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df,id+cat~item,value.var = "item",fun.aggregate =length)
```

Comment: Have you checked the output of this?

Comment: This doesn't list the category A items vs category B items